# On some inequality involving the Riemann zeta function integral at $\Re(s)=1/2$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I recently saw on p.$458$ of Montgomery-Vaugahn's ''Multiplicative number theory'' that the inequality

$$\int_{1}^{T} \zeta(1/2 + it) \mathrm{d}t = T + O(T^{1/2})$$

holds uniformly for $T\geq 2$, where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function. From this result, it clearly follows that

$$\Bigg| \int_{1}^{T} \zeta(1/2+it) \mathrm{d}T \Bigg|\geq T^{1/2}$$

for all $T\geq T_0$. I need help on finding the $T_0$.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @AndrásBátkai, my question (put otherwise) is does anyone know the $T_0$ that i'm looking for. I thought it was quite clear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the person behind all these user accounts does not seem to be interested in returning to this question, and has not been recently active under the user account used to post this question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question again, since the person behind this and other accounts seems unwilling to admit to sockpuppeting